# How to reassign value to globally defined variable in spring thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

here is my html code i tried.

```
<body th:with="firstId=null,lastId='123'">
  <table>
   <tr th:each="document, state : ${data}">
   <td th:with="firstId = ${state.first ? document[_id] : 'abc'}" th:text="${firstId}"></td>
  </table>
  <div th:text="${firstId}">something</div>
</body>
```

What i am trying to achieve is i would like to assign only first value to firstId variable and after loop completion i would like to print firstId variable outside the loop just after  tag.

how could i achieve this?

Comment: Declaring and setting variables is done using th:with. However, variables are only set within the scope of the element where the change was made (scope in this case means the element where the variable was set, and all its child elements).

Comment: thats why i declared the variables in body attribute to make it available for entire body